# cannot openshared object file, with node-gyp in nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I'm using node-gyp to create a native addon on nodejs.
in local machine i build an addon with nodejs and it works fine,
taking file_name.node (binary file ) to another host machine i can't launch, I get error because he can not find the shared lib used, so i have two solutions, both of them works :
in the host machine setting export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/shard/lib
or copy this shared lib to /usr/lib
Im asking if there is another solution?
Like doing some config on bynding.gyp for example